# How do you find something in an array that would match keywords from a text file and while doing a regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm at a loss at trying to find out how to match the keywords in my keywords text which are:

```
NetworkManager
dhclient
dbus
```

My code currently looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Compare;

my $syslogFile = 'syslog';
open (my $syslogInfo, '<', $syslogFile) or die "Could not open $syslogFile";

my $keywordFile = 'keyword';
open (my $keywordInfo, '<', $keywordFile) or die "Could not open $keywordFile";

while(my @keywordArray = <$keywordInfo>)
{
    print "@keywordArray\n";
}


while(my @syslogLine = <$syslogInfo>)
{
    print "@syslogLine\n";
}
```

and now I am stuck on how to get these 2 text files to work together and get the desired result.

What Im trying to do is to have things in my syslog txt for example:

```
Dec 27 21:17:52 osboxes rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.12.0" x-pid="695" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
Dec 27 21:18:05 osboxes anacron[634]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
Dec 27 21:18:05 osboxes anacron[634]: Normal exit (1 job run)
Dec 27 21:22:29 osboxes NetworkManager[686]: <info>    lease time 1800
Dec 27 21:22:29 osboxes NetworkManager[686]: <info>    domain name 'localdomain'
```

To have it matched with the keywords and only print the lines that have the keywords in it so that it will only print:

```
Dec 27 21:22:29 osboxes NetworkManager[686]: <info>    lease time 1800
Dec 27 21:22:29 osboxes NetworkManager[686]: <info>    domain name 'localdomain'
```

I have tried out using IF by doing this:

```
if(my @syslogLine = (/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\s(\d\d)\s(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)\s[a-zA-Z]*\s(@keywordArray).*/s))
{
    open(outputFile, ">>output");
    print outputFile "@syslogLine\n";
}
```

but this gives me the errors:

```
Possible unintended of @keywordArray
Global symbol "@keywordArray requires explict package name
```

Im guessing that perl doesn't like having an array in the regex?
I just couldn't get my head around this problem.

Answer (score 3):

The common approach is to build a regex from the keywords, then read the second file and match each line against the keyword:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $keywordFile = 'keyword';
open my $KW, '<', $keywordFile or die "Could not open $keywordFile";
chomp( my @keywords = <$KW> );
my $regex = join '|', map quotemeta, @keywords;

my $syslogFile = 'syslog';
open my $SYS, '<', $syslogFile or die "Could not open $syslogFile";

while(<$SYS>) {
    print if /$regex/;
}
```

Comment: Did not thought about thinking about this at all. Thank you very much! I totally tunnel visioned on trying to make the keyword inside the regex work.

Comment: @Shiena might want to try *Parse::Syslog* if you need something more robust and flexible

Comment: @PatoSáinz just question, I read about syslog but couldn't understand to well about it. So, does it parse a file called syslog anywhere on the computer if so, what if there's more than 1 file called syslog but in a different location?

Comment: @PatoSáinz oh unfortunately, i cannot do parse:syslog as the exercise that I am doing requires to utilise regex where it is possible

Comment: @choroba would it be possible to explain what is happening in the my $regex = join '|', map quotemeta, @keywords; because I am not very familiar with the map quotemeta

Comment: @Shiena [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) and [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) both have entries in perldoc.